# Why R does not understand that the for loop should be bypassed?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have this *for* loop (for simplicity, let us assume that it justs prints the index)

```
for (i in seq(from = left_index, to = right_index, by = reverse)) {
     print(i)
   }
```

I don't know in advance `left_index`, `right_index` and `reverse` can either be 1 or -1 (forward or backward)

It turns out that I can face the situation where `left_index=0`, `right_index=1` and `reverse=-1`. I am just expecting that the loop is bypassed (which is in fact what happens in Matlab, from which I am translating code) but it seem that R renders life complicated and outputs

```
Error in seq.default(0, 1, -1) : wrong sign in 'by' argument
```

How is it possible to simply ask R to discard the loop when one would expect to be the case, as in the previous case ?

EDIT, with Matlab example, for information:

```
for i=0:-1:1
     disp(i)
end
```

outputs nothing (but no error), this is also what I am expecting

```
for i=2:-1:1
     disp(i)
end
```

outputs 2; 1

Comment: The issue isn't the loop, the `seq()` function errors before the loop is initialized - and it makes sense that it does as how can you have a sequence from 0 to 1 that increments by -1?

Comment: @RitchieSacramento yes, obviously. But in this case, I am just expecting that the loop is skipped. This is the behaviour I am expecting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the `for` loop, and everything to do with the result of `seq(from = left_index, to = right_index, by = reverse)`.  If that function returns an empty vector, the loop won't do anything.

So the problem (and the cause of your error) is that `seq()` doesn't like being called as `seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = -1)`.  That makes sense:  how can a sequence of -1 steps start at 0 and end at 1?

The easiest solution to this is not to use `seq()`, use a custom function that accepts those inputs, for example:

```
myseq <- function(from, to, by) {
  if (by*(to - from) < 0)
    numeric()
  else
    seq(from, to, by)
}
```

This assumes you want `from=0, to=0, by=1` to run one step; if you don't want it to do anything, then use `<=` in the test.

Then your loop would be

```
for (i in myseq(from = left_index, to = right_index, by = reverse))
```

and it should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

How Matlab does this seems very concerning (if your claim is true). That's a recipe for hidden bugs. In R you could use error handling or do this:

```
if (sign(right_index - left_index) == sign(reverse) || right_index - left_index == 0) {
  for (i in seq(from = left_index, to = right_index, by = reverse)) {
    print(i)
  }
}
```

Comment: See my edit for the Matlab concern ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple way to skip the for loop in that case is to define one `if` before the loop excutes. For example `tryCatch()` is a good way to do this. I will provide an example:

```
left_index <- sample(-1:1, 1)
right_index <- sample(-1:1, 1)
step <- sample(c(-1,1), 1)
tryCatch({
  for (i in seq(left_index, right_index, by=step)) {
    print(i)
  }
},error=function(error_message) {
  cat("Bypassed", sep='\n')
})
```

As you can see, we can tell the algorithm to do nothing when an error occurs and move on. We can even ignore the `cat` function not to print any text.

Comment: The potential issue with this approach is that every error is skipped and not just the specific error from `seq`.